# Trying to find out which PHP file to edit

Tags: php, oscommerce

I want to make a simple change in my OSCommerce webstore. To uncheck a radio button that is now checked my default. Many customers don't bother to read the page and they just click 'next'. So i want to have no default value checked so the customer is forced to make a choice.

So i used FireBug to find the source code under the button which is:

```
<td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="flat_flat" checked="checked" /></td>
```

To a PHP newby like me it seems i just just remove checked="checked".

However i found it impossible to find in which PHP file i should make the modification. The page itself is named 'checkout_shipping.php' but upon inspection of the php file it is not there.

So i downloaded the COMPLETE webstore and used Agent ransack to search each and every file.

Nothing!

Can anyone help me to figure this out? I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, HTML for that input is dynamically created in the checkout_shipping.php file by the function `tep_draw_radio_field`.  There's a block of code that loops through each available shipping module and creates a radio for each one.

The "checked" default is actually a cause of the shipping class's `cheapest()` method being run higher up in the same file.

You could comment this line of code by changing it from:

```
if ( !tep_session_is_registered('shipping') || ( tep_session_is_registered('shipping') && ($shipping == false) && (tep_count_shipping_modules() > 1) ) ) $shipping = $shipping_modules->cheapest();
```

To:

```
//if ( !tep_session_is_registered('shipping') || ( tep_session_is_registered('shipping') && ($shipping == false) && (tep_count_shipping_modules() > 1) ) ) $shipping = $shipping_modules->cheapest();
```

That should leave all of the radios unchecked on the user's initial visit to the shipping page.  Also, it leaves intact the default selected radio if the user comes back to the shipping page later in the checkout process to change their shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use jQuery to manipulate an element once the page has fully rendered the form.

Some samples (either should work, providing alternates "just in case"):

- `$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping"]').removeAttr("checked");`
- `$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping"]').attr("checked", false);`
- `$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping"]').prop("checked", false);`

However I'm not sure which page you'd be adding this code to. I guess if there's a view page that renders the content first, such as a /directory/view/index.php type of file?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. Do you mean completely removing the line if ( !tep_session_is_registered('shipping') || ( tep_session_is_registered('shipping') && ($shipping == false) && (tep_count_shipping_modules() > 1) ) ) $shipping = $shipping_modules->cheapest(); from checkout shipping.php?

Comment: Hi @Dragonlover I think your comment would go with the answer below but thanks for your response.  It does appear that the form inputs are rendered to the page, and that you will have to do the coding to handle the un-checking.  Lastly  have you tried using jQuery to un-check the box once it has been rendered to the page?

Comment: Sorry but i have no clue as to what you mean. I don;t really know PHP or JQuery. I justed want to have a radio button unchecked. I thought i could do it myself....

Comment: I understand @Dragonlover if it's easier to change the PHP code before it renders the form, then you accomplish your goal as well.  jQuery is something interesting and worth the time learning. If you have learned javascript to any extent then learning jQuery will be very easy to pick up.

Comment: To answer you comment about my answer above using the PHP method, you can simply comment the line, instead of removing it completely.  That way, if you ever decide do reinstate the line, you can.  Refer to my updated answer above for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Hello, Thanks again for your reply. I am going to try it out :)